# Any way for cmake command to use parameters in a file?

Tags: cmake

`cmake` may take a lot of command parameters, for example

```
cmake -GNinja -DAAA=BBB ...
```

Any convenient way for Windows?

For example, save the parameters in a file like "cmake_cfg.debug", and call

```
camke --config_file=cmake_cfg.debug
```

Comment: A `custom_settings.cmake` helps, 1. set variables in the file 2. include the file to use the variables

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash-like a shell, you could do  something like:

```
$ cmake $(xargs < /path/to/file) ..
```

In your case, the file would look like (the individual values need to be separated by whitespace chars):

```
-GNinja -DAAA=BBB
-DOtherParam=Value
```

Comment: I'm using both Windows and Linux. What about Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not work for the generator choice, but for all the cache entries you could create a cmake file using the `set()` commands to set cache entries and use the `-C` option to tell `cmake` to use this file to prepopulate the cache:

**prepopulate_cache.cmake**

```
set(AAA "BBB" CACHE STRING "documentation string of AAA")
...
```

---

```
cmake -G Ninja -C prepopulate_cache.cmake <source_dir>
```

Comment: so no built in way, thanks